# Como fazer o Bootstrap funcionar nas opções do Tema – ADMIN

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-3, bootstrap, wordpress-theme

Não consigo fazer o Bootstrap trabalhar nas opções da API de Configurações no meu tema WordPress.

Eu adicionei na action `admin_enqueue_scripts` juntamente com outros JS e CSS

```
Wp_register_style ('custom_wp_admin_css', get_template_directory_uri (). '/css/bootstrap.min.css', false);
Wp_enqueue_style ('custom_wp_admin_css');
```

E tentei muitos artigos, mas ainda não consigo resolver. Tem alguma forma do Bootstrap funcionar corretamente no admin do Wordpress?